# $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$ then $X/H_1\cong X/H_2$ as covering space of $X/G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let $X$ be a path-connected and locally path-connected topological space. The action of a topolgical group $G$ on $X$ is a covering space action. For any subgroup $H < G$, we have a composition of covering space $X \rightarrow X/H \rightarrow X/G$.
>
> Prove that $X/H_1 \rightarrow X/G$ and $X/H_2 \rightarrow X/G$ are isomorphic as covering spaces if and only if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$.

I am working on this problem (Hatcher 1.3.24(b)) and now I am stuck on the "if" direction.

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361553/group-action-and-covering-spaces), the answer gives a map which may be proved to be an isomorphism. I think once I prove that the map is well-defined, I would define the inverse of the map in a similar way and prove that the map is indeed an isomorphism. But I stuck on proveing that the map is well-defined (That is, if $H_1x_1=H_1x_2$, then $H_2x_1=H_2x_2$).

May I please ask for some explaination on this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That map is not well-defined (unless $H_1=H_2$).  To get a well-defined map, you need to use the assumption that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate, so suppose $g\in G$ is such that $gH_1g^{-1}=H_2$.  Then you can consider the map that sends $H_1x$ to $H_2gx$.  This is well-defined since if $H_1x=H_1y$ then $x=hy$ for some $h\in H_1$, and then $$gx=ghy=(ghg^{-1})gy$$ where $ghg^{-1}\in H_2$ so $H_2gx=H_2gy$.